# Django Channels: Can someone provide a very simple working example of data binding?

Tags: django, data-binding, django-channels

I'm learning how to implement Django channels into my website but I have problems understand the documentation (http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binding.html). There are not many examples on the internet. Can someone provide me a working source code of data binding with decent commenting?

Answer (score 0):

For django-channels 1 - https://bitbucket.org/voron-raven/chat/src/aec8536dba2cc5f0faa42305dcd7a49d330a8b54/core/models.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#models.py-242
It's simple chat site with a chatbot -  http://chat.mkeda.me

Example of data binding:

```
class MessageBinding(WebsocketBinding):
    model = Message
    stream = 'messages'
    fields = ['__all__']

    @classmethod
    def group_names(cls, instance):
        """
        Returns the iterable of group names to send the object to based on the
        instance and action performed on it.
        """
        return ['thread-{}'.format(instance.thread.pk)]

    def has_permission(self, user, action, pk):
        """
        Return True if the user can do action to the pk, False if not.
        User may be AnonymousUser if no auth hooked up/they're not logged in.
        Action is one of "create", "delete", "update".
        """
        if action == 'create':
            return True

        return user.is_superuser
```

In django-channels 2 binding was removed - http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/one-to-two.html?highlight=binding#removed-components
You can use signals to send updates to your groups.

Comment: please not just refer to other sites but also quote the important parts here